# Exception when trying to use icons from Asset Catalog in iOS project with Xamarin TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, asset-catalog, tabbedpage

I create a Xamarin Forms project in VS 2017 and started by adding a `TabbedPage` with three tabs. I then added the icons to the Android (in Resources/drawable) and iOS (Asset Catalogs/Icons) projects.

When I start the project on Android it works fine, but on iOS I get an exception that the `UIImage` cannot be loaded because `initWithCOntentsOfFile` returned nil. Which is actually correct, because that's not the correct method to use to access Assets. But it's the `TabbedPage` calling the method, so I cannot do anything about it.

The `TabbetPage` looks pretty basic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GreenThumb"
            x:Class="GreenThumb.MainPage">
    <NavigationPage Title="Today" Icon="current.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Current />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Overview" Icon="overview.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Overview />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Settings" Icon="settings.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Settings />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

And the Asset Catalog looks like this:
[image: iOS Asset Catalog for the Icons]

This problem seems to be pretty old, but I haven't found any solutions aside some very dirty hacks.

Is there a clean solution out there? Or do I just have to add all my images in the Resources folder instead of Asset Catalogs?

Comment: You can explicitly assign the source location in the xaml I believe. using the onplatform designation.

Comment: But what about Android then? I want to support both platforms.

Comment: using the onplatform designation you would simply set one for each platform in your .Forms xaml, just allows you a little bit of flexibility where it's required.

Comment: also second to that, have you actually added all of the images into your asset catalogue for 'current' ?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled in the past on this issue. It seems that icons for tabbed pages are not working in iOS if placed in the .xcassets.
I moved those .png files inside the Resources folder and that made the magic.
I suppose it's a kind of bug on Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

The same error was occurring to me, and I was putting the images on the `.xcassets` on iOS.

When I placed the images on the Resources folder, they appeared normally on my TabbedPage.

In the [official Xamarin documentation about images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/), they say to put the images in the Resources folder.

> iOS - Place images in the Resources folder with Build Action:
>   BundleResource. Retina versions of the image should also be supplied -
>   two and three times the resolution with a @2x or @3x suffixes on the
>   filename before the file extension (eg. myimage@2x.png).

I place all my images in the `.xcassets` folder, they apparently work well, but it seems not to work on every case.